How to solve the ARCH effect problem in estimating linear bivariate regression model?
I estimated a linear bivariate regression model by OLS method.
I did the ARCH effect test. And there is the presence of ARCH effect in residuals.
How can I deal with the presence of ARCH effect while estimating the bivariate linear model?

Estimate a GARCH model where the conditional mean equation ($\mu_t$ below) corresponds to your bivariate regression. This way you will estimate the regression coefficients efficiently and will have appropriate standard errors that account for the ARCH pattern.
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 x_{t}, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \alpha_s u_{t-s}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \beta_r \sigma_{t-r}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.D(0,1),
\end{aligned}
where $D$ is some probability distribution with zero mean and unit variance.
(Of course, you do not have to worry about ARCH in cross-sectional data; it only makes sense for time series.)

Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain this more in mathematical way? And please suggest any source to understand that? Because my knowledge is very limited. Thank you.

@1190, here you go. Aside from the fact that the conditional mean of $y$ depends on $x$, this is just the standard GARCH(r,s) model. Regarding a source, I do not remember one that covers this kind of model specifically, sorry.
